# jquery move element before closest

Tags: jquery

In each .content-cont I'm trying to move the .media-cont before the nearest .middle but I can't make it work. I'm sure it's a dumb mistake but I've tried to figure it out and the best I can do is that all the .media-cont get inserted before the middle .middle p tag

Here's my code...

```js
$('.content-cont').each((i, el) => {
  let $p = $(el).find('p');
  let mid = Math.floor($p.length / 2);
  $p.eq(mid).addClass('middle');
});

$('.content-cont').each(function(i, e) {
  $e = $(e);
  let img = $('.media-cont');
  $e.find(img).insertBefore($(this).closest($('.middle')));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content-cont">
  <div class="media-cont"></div>
  <div class="text-cont">
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p class="middle">Some text</p>
    <p>some text</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="content-cont">
  <div class="media-cont"></div>
  <div class="text-cont">
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p class="middle">Some text</p>
    <p>some text</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="content-cont">
  <div class="media-cont"></div>
  <div class="text-cont">
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p class="middle">Some text</p>
    <p>some text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overthinking it

I assume I could remove the hardcoded class="middle"

```js
$('.content-cont').each((i, el) => {
  let $p = $(el).find('p');
  let mid = Math.floor($p.length / 2);
  $p.eq(mid).addClass('middle');
  $('.media-cont',el).insertBefore($('.middle',el)); // or use the eq here too
});
```

```css
.middle { color: red }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content-cont">
  <div class="media-cont">Media</div>
  <div class="text-cont">
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>some text</p>
  </div>
</div>
<hr/>
<div class="content-cont">
  <div class="media-cont">Media</div>
  <div class="text-cont">
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>some text</p>
  </div>
</div>
<hr/>
<div class="content-cont">
  <div class="media-cont">Media</div>
  <div class="text-cont">
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>some text</p>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>some text</p>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>some text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah thanks! Im still not sure what i and el do but it works. Does i give each p tag an index number allowing us to find the mid point?

Comment: i is the index and el is the element. If you use function instead of arrow, you can use $(this) - the el is the DOM element and it gives the scope in `$('.media-cont',el)` as in find me the media-cont in THIS div. The rest of the code is YOUR code - the mid is counting the number of Ps and adds .middle to the one nearest the middle